# Check to see if URLs exist in Ruby

Tags: ruby, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if URL exists in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908017/check-if-url-exists-in-ruby)

Is it possible to check if a URL exists with Ruby?

Comment: It has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908017/check-if-url-exists-in-ruby

Answer (score 1):

It has been asked and answered before.

Please check it here: [Check if URL exists in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908017/check-if-url-exists-in-ruby)

I hope it helps

Comment: I am sorry. I should have looked more carefully. Thanks!