# How do I check if a file exists using its URL without downloading it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I need to write code which will determine if a file exists by checking its URL.

Currently I implement this:

```
error_code = 400;
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI(url));
return response.code.to_i < error_code;
```

But, it's not working right because each time it downloads the file, which is really slow if I have big files or a lot of them.

How do I determine if a file exists on the remote side without downloading it?

Comment: Do you have access to the server side code? Can you change the controllers?

Comment: Don't end your lines with `;`. This isn't C or Perl.

Comment: See [HTTP verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Verbs#Request_methods), specifically the `HEAD` method. If you know the verbs better you'll find it easier to find a way to get stuff like this done, regardless of library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if URL exists in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908017/check-if-url-exists-in-ruby)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want to use Rubys included `Net::HTTP` then you can do it this way:

```
uri = URI(url)

request = Net::HTTP.new uri.host
response= request.request_head uri.path
return response.code.to_i == 200
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that `Net::HTTP` is included in the stand Ruby spec.

Comment: be aware of other valid response codes, like 301 for example, the file can actually be there, in the next url to be retrieved from the first request.
i.e : tinyurl

Comment: To use `Net::HTTP`, import it: `require 'net/http'`

Answer (score 6):

With the `rest-client` gem installed, do something like this

```
require "rest-client"
 
begin
  exists = RestClient.head("http://google.com").code == 200
rescue RestClient::Exception => error
  exists = (error.http_code != 404) 
end
```

Then "exists" is a boolean depending whether if it exists or not. This will only get the header information, not the file, so it should be the same for small or big files.

Comment: Thats good, but I don't want to use additional gems or libs for that

Comment: Understood, unfortunately I'm not sure of a way to do it without using something like rest-client. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I'd write it this way:

```
require 'net/http'

ERROR_CODE = 400

response = Net::HTTP.start('www.example.net', 80) do |http|
  http.request_head('/index.html') 
end

puts response.code.to_i < ERROR_CODE
```

Which outputs `true` because I got a `302` for the `response.code`.

Comment: I try do the things this way, but it throws me unknown host exception

Comment: I can't duplicate that. It's working for me using Ruby 1.9.3. You don't show what URL you are trying to reach, so it's impossible for us to help you with that.