# How do I properly ask a user for a URL and check to see if that site is up?

Tags: ruby

What I'm trying to do is ask a user for a URL, then query that URL to see if it's up, and respond with "Response OK!" as the title describes.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'url'
```

Here I'm asking a user for a url and attempting to define that string as a variable:

```
puts "\n\nWhat website would you like to check?\n\n"
  userinput = gets.chomp
```

Here I'm checking for an HTTP response with that variable $userinput

```
def main
  while true
    uri = URI.parse($userinput)
    response = Net::HTTP::get_response(uri)
    if response.code == "200"
      puts "Response OK!"
    else
      puts "Received #{response.code} code. Probing again in 15s..."
    end
    sleep(15)
  end
end

# Exit on CTRL-C SIGINT 
Signal.trap("INT") {
  puts "\nUser exited."
  exit
}

main ()
```

Here is the code in action. I don't know how else to paste this:

```
What website would you like to check?

http://www.reddit.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from prober.rb:33:in `<main>'
prober.rb:14:in `main': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)               (ArgumentError)
```

Removing the space between main () results in this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
5: from prober.rb:33:in `<main>'
4: from prober.rb:16:in `main'
3: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri/common.rb:237:in `parse'
2: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:73:in `parse'
1: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:15:in `split'
```

/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:18:in `rescue in split': bad URI(is not URI?):  (URI::InvalidURIError)

Comment: If looking for a way how to implement a url valid checker, take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5908162/5025116) answer. Any other question could be better adding the corresponding error stacktrace.

Comment: What website would you like to check?

http://www.reddit.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
 1: from prober.rb:33:in `<main>'
prober.rb:14:in `main': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)

Comment: You can edit your question, adding the output you've commented. That and any other info. you can add to give us better understanding of your problem.

Comment: For that specific problem, remove the space between `main` and the parenthesis. Ruby, due to the flexibility on accepting method calls without parenthesis is using the empty parenthesis as a method argument, hence your ArgumentError.

Comment: I see the link, but that's checking a static url every time. I want it to check against a variable that the user defines, eg $userinput and the use of gets.chomp -- removing the space between main () gives me even more errors hehe

Comment: Note that checking `response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)` is more reliable than checking if the code is 200. It will cover all the valid 2xx response codes. You'll also have to [handle redirection](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.4/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Following+Redirection). You may wish to use [the `http` gem](https://github.com/httprb/http) instead which can [handle redirection for you](https://github.com/httprb/http/wiki/Redirects).

Comment: Oh excellent, that's exactly where I need to go next, because it's throwing a 301 at me

Comment: Guys thank you so much for this, I am just barely cutting my teeth and this helps tremendously. The HTTPSuccess tip is gold. I'm going to see about implementing the http gem instead for the redirection mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this ArgumentError problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from prober.rb:33:in `<main>'
prober.rb:14:in `main': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

remove the space between main and the parenthesis. Ruby, due to the flexibility on accepting method calls without parenthesis is using the empty parenthesis as a method argument.

If you want to pass the user input to your main method, then you need to declare a parameter for it (better than using global variables).

You can use gets.chomp to store the user input, and when you call the main function, you pass that as argument.

So that can be like:

```
def main(user_input)
  while true
    uri = URI.parse(user_input)
    response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
    ...
  end
end

puts "\n\nWhat website would you like to check?\n\n"
userinput = gets.chomp
main(userinput)
```

Notice the use of `()` in "void context" is interpreted as a `nil` object. Which is clearly valid for throwing an ArgumentError exception.

```
p ()
# nil
```